# Alpakka search in elasticsearch without scrolling

Tags: elasticsearch, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

can someone help me how can I search without using the scroll feature inside the elastic with alpakka.

I want to use alpakka or akka-stream to reactively send a query to elastic without scrolling, But the only thing I found was "ElasticsearchSource" in alpakka, which sends search requests using scroll.

In aplakka [ElasticsearchSourceSettings document](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/elasticsearch.html#source-configuration) there is two parameters for control scroll scan:

1. bufferSize => ElasticsearchSource retrieves messages from
   Elasticsearch by scroll scan. This buffer size is used as the
   scroll size.
2. scrollDuration => ElasticsearchSource retrieves messages from
   Elasticsearch by scroll scan. This parameter is used as a scroll
   value.

and in [githup source code](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/d192d049b6b25291c8887252c39d87e08cd2b076/elasticsearch/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/elasticsearch/impl/ElasticsearchSourceStage.scala#L102) The only function that sends an elastic request is "sendScrollScanRequest".

Does setting these values to zero disable scroll scanning?

Is it possible to send search requests without scrolling using alpakka or akka-stream?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.